# Execute custom logic after Mezzanine form submission with page_processors.py

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I have a question regarding page_processors.py. I've made a contact page with a form through the mezzanine admin and I have some logic that I'd like executed upon completion of that form. After reading the documentation, I found that [creating a page_processors.py](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-processors) module in my app should help take care of that, but the file isn't being touched (ie, I can't get to the debugger inside it). Can anyone here help?

Here's my page_processors.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from mezzanine.pages.page_processors import processor_for
from mezzanine.forms.models import Form
import requests

#do some testing to see that this code is correct
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
@processor_for(slug="contact")
def form_view(request):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you shouldn't name your app "site", interferes with an existing module named site (facepalm).